# How can I do binary search in java ArrayList<Long>?

Tags: java, search, methods, binary, long-integer

I am trying to make binary search in ArrayList, but the binarySearch method does not work for Long, as well as Double and Float. My code is

```
import java.util.*;

 public class BinarySearchInArrayList
 {
     public static void main(String[]args)
     {
         ArrayList<Long> ar = new ArrayList();

         for(long l = 1;l<100000;l++)
         {
             ar.add(l);
         }

         System.out.println("arraylist: "+ar); 
         System.out.println("Which number's index do you want to know? ");
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         int p = scan.nextInt();
         int index = Collections.binarySearch(ar,p);
         System.out.println("number "+p+" has index "+index);
     }
```

When I use Integer instead of `Long`, it works fine, but I want to make it with `Long`. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int p = scan.nextInt();
int index = Collections.binarySearch(ar,p);
```

Above should be:

```
long index = Collections.binarySearch(ar,p);
long p = scan.nextLong();
```